# elasticsearch fail to start gives erorr

Tags: java, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, elasticsearch

when I run command to start elasticsearch ..

```
/elasticsearch -f
```

gives bunch of errors like

> ElasticSearchIllegalStateException[Failed to obtain node lock, is the following location writable?: [/home/anish/elasticsearch/data/elasticsearch]]
>
> IOException[failed to obtain lock on /home/anish/elasticsearch/data/elasticsearch/nodes/49]
>
> ```
>   IOException[Cannot create directory: /home/anish/elasticsearch/data/elasticsearch/nodes/49]
> ```

dont know how to get rid of it..pl help

Answer (score 2):

Look in `/etc/sysconfig/elasticsearch` for the values of `ES_USER` and `ES_GROUP` -- the default setting for both is `elasticsearch`. If that user cannot write to your data directory, then you will see this error.  Since the data directory appears to be under your home directory, this could be the issue.  You can either modify the settings for `ES_USER` and `ES_GROUP` or change the permissions for the data directory.

Comment: In my default setup from the .deb package the config file is /etc/default/elasticsearch and ES_USER and ES_USER were commented and needed to be uncommented for the daemon to start with no errors

Answer (score 1):

There could be multiple causes of this error, Elasticsearch stores its data in the file system and location of that is specified in `elasticsearch.yml` and while starting elasticsearch, it checks whether it can write data to that location or not, if yes, then it would acquire a lock on that location so that other process can't write to that location which prevents the data loss and corruption.

Also, this depends on the version of Elasticsearch, in current major version 7.X, Elasticsearch changed the way it writes to the same location when there are multiple installations on the same machine and before that it used `node.max_local_storage_nodes` to allow multiple installations on the same machine.

**Tips to fix the issue**

1. Check if multiple Elasticsearch process is running and you intend to do it.
2. Check if Elasticsearch have write access to the location, as mentioned in the previous answer.
3. Check the version of elasticsearch and see if you are using the correct configuration.